# gensim error : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable during training in Fasttext

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, gensim, fasttext

While implementing `Fasttext` in Python 3.7, I am facing an unexpected scenario related to `Exception in thread`, which leads to

> NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The error (screenshot) of full stack trace is as follows: 
[image]

What exactly is this issue in  gensim python?

The code I have tried:

```
import nltk, re
import string
from collections import Counter 
from string import punctuation
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg, stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from gensim.models import FastText

def preprocessing():
    raw_data = (gutenberg.raw('shakespeare-hamlet.txt'))
    tokens = word_tokenize(raw_data)
    tokens = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
    #remove punctuation from each word
    table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
    stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    global words
    words = [word for word in stripped if word.isalpha()]
    sw = (stopwords.words('english'))
    sw1= (['.', ',', '"', '?', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}'])

    stop=sw+sw1
    words = [w for w in words if not w in stop]
preprocessing()

def freq_count():
    fd = nltk.FreqDist(words)
freq_count()

def intialize_word_embedding():
    model = FastText([words], size = 100, sg = 1, window = 5, min_count = 5, workers = 4)
    model.train([words], total_examples=len(words), epochs=10)
    model.init_sims(replace=True)
    model_name = "mcft"
    model.save(model_name)
    print(len(model.wv.vocab))
intialize_word_embedding()
def load_model():
    model = FastText.load('mcft')
    similarities = model.wv.most_similar('hamlet')
    for word, score in similarities:
        print(word , score)
    print(model.wv.similarity('hamlet', 'king'))
load_model()
```

Note: The model works perfectly, when I comment the

```
model.train([words], total_examples=len(words), epochs=10)`
```

line in the above shown code.

Comment: Add the full stack trace, please. This is especially important since no one has a copy of your shakespeare-hamlet.txt file, and therefore we can't run it ourselves (although I suppose *i could* go download one...but I am lazy).

Comment: Thanks but it is a standard file readily available in nltk library. No need to put the same shakespeare.txt separately.

Comment: Oh I see! Still, add the full trace (even if it's large)

Comment: Sure. I will add.

Comment: @MattMessersmith, please see my edit.